# MismatchedTokenException: expecting "set", found '='

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In my java spring boot application, i am working with postgresql. I am trying to run the below query

```
String update = "update User" +
            "set temporaryRandomToken = :randomToken" +
            "where id = :userId";
     org.hibernate.query.Query<?> sql = createHql(update)
             .setParameter("randomToken", "12aswqq")
             .setParameter("userId", 1);
```

The problem is, when i run the query it complains with

```
MismatchedTokenException: expecting "set", found '='
```

The `userId`, and the `randomToken` must change dynamically, so do not offer my a static query string.

Answer (score 2):

You need a space in the beginning of 2 lines (before "set" and "where"):

```
String update = "update User" +
        " set temporaryRandomToken = :randomToken" +
        " where id = :userId";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a space. Change

```
String update = "update User" +
```

to:

```
String update = "update User " +
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you forgot to add an extra whitespace between 'User' and 'set'